# Radius of Convergence when using Series[]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I want to write function `expand[f]` which gives the Taylor series expansion of $f(x)$ up to $O(x^4)$ in $\TeX$ form, as well as return the radius of convergence.

I have written:

```
expand = Function[f, TeXForm[Series[f, {x, 0, 3}]]
SumConvergence[f, x]];
```

but `SumConvergence` requires the general term of a sequence, so the syntax written there is incorrect. Is there a command in stead of `SumConvergence` which will allow me to do this?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html

Answer (score 3):

As a start on the radius of convergence question:

```
ClearAll[rc];
rc[f_, {x_, x0_}] := Reduce[
  SumConvergence[
   FullSimplify[
     SeriesCoefficient[
      f, {x, x0, \[FormalN]}], \[FormalN] \[Element] Integers && 
      n >= 0] (x - x0)^\[FormalN], \[FormalN]],
  Abs[x - x0]]
```

Examples.  `SumConvergence` is a bit challenged by `SeriesCoefficient` tendency to return `DifferenceRoot` object.  `FullSimplify` helps but is not always sufficient.

```
rc[1/(4 x^2 + 1), {x, 1}]
(*  Abs[-1 + x] < Sqrt[5]/2  *)

rc[Exp[4 x], {x, 1}]
(*  True  *)
```

This one needs extra help.

```
rc[ArcTan[x], {x, 0}]
MapAt[
 FullSimplify[# /. \[FormalN] -> 2 \[FormalN] + 1,
   \[FormalN] \[Element] Integers && n >= 0] &, 
 First[%], 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*  Abs[x] < 1  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expand[f_] := {TeXForm[Series[f, {x, 0, 3}]], SumConvergence[f, x]}
```

Example:

```
expand[n^x]
```

> {"1+x \log (n)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(n)+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \log ^3(n)+O\left(x^4\right)",Abs[n]<1}

Comment: It doesn't work for series like $e^{4x}$. This should converge for all real numbers.