# Power Series and Interval of Convergence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How could I find the power series and interval of convergence for x/(3+x^2)?

Comment: For series, use the command [Series](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) and for rc, see this [radius-of-convergence-when-using-series](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140271/radius-of-convergence-when-using-series)

Comment: If this is a math question, ask at http://math.stackexchange.com. Otherwise, you could also use `SeriesCoefficient[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := x/(3 + x^2)
```

The coefficients of the power series are

```
coef[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n},
   Assumptions -> n >= 0] // FullSimplify

(* 3^(-(1/2) - n/2) Sin[(n π)/2] *)

sum = Inactive[Sum][coef[n] x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Verifying the series expansion,

```
f[x] == sum // Activate // Simplify

(* True *)
```

For the sum to be convergent

```
SumConvergence[coef[n] x^n, n]

(* Abs[x] < Sqrt[3] *)
```

Checking,

```
Assuming[Abs[x] < Sqrt[3], sum // Activate]

(* x/(3 + x^2) *)

Assuming[Abs[x] >= Sqrt[3], sum // Activate]
```

[image]